# histogram on matplotlib for a

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am new here, although I have been reading answers to questions for quite a while. I have a problem, I have a seismic hazard curve looking roughly as follows:

[image: Hazard curve]

I need to plot it like an histogram. That is what a hazard curve looks like - I would need to plot the median as a histogram

I have tried to use `plt.hist` as follows:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
```

where `x` is my frequency data array:

```
x = [1.00E-02, 1.00E-03, 1.00E-04, 1.00E-05, 1.00E-06, 1.00E-07, 1.00E-08, 1.00E-09, 1.00E-10]
```

but it gives me back an empty image. I think it is because it's used to plot probability density functions (and mine is not a probability density function) but I am not sure if I am right. Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Hi, mind fixing the title? Looks like a word or two are missing.

Comment: If you are passing the list `x` to `hist` then a histogram should be plotted, so I don't know why an empty image is being returned (I certainly see one on my machine when I execute your example code). What exactly are you trying to histogram? To me, the array `x` just looks like the values on the y-axis of your example graph at which all three curves are evaluated. Do you want the median of the x-value at each y-value? (i.e. median pga amplitude at each annual frequency of exceedance)

Comment: Your example should work just fine. Maybe you see an empty image because you plotted other stuff in the same figure and have a wrong scale? Try to open a new figure with `plt.figure()` before using `plt.hist`?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments I have been able to get a plot of my x data set, my scale was indeed wrong. But this hasn't solved my problem.

The x data set I am using is the median y value (blue line and dots on the graph). I do have the corresponding pga values too.
What I'd want to plot is discrete version of that graph. Will try to explain it better:
bins of let's say width 1pga
height of the bars needs to be proportional to the y value and not to the number of data points I have - this is because my data is already a frequency distribution of the pga.
I hope this is more clear.